# PHP mysqli check if username/password are correct

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to connect with PHP mysqli to a database but first I want to check if the username/password is correct.

I have already tried this
`if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}`

But it is not working correctly when I am trying to connect without a password like this. (the result is not an error)

`$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$username = "skjhfdsfkjgh";
$mysqli= new mysqli($host, $username, $password);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database might allow you to connect without a password while not showing you the databases connected with that account which might explain the absence of errors in the connect. You might want to select the db you want to use and see if that throws errors since you are not using password.